# findViewById for WebView on another Class

Tags: java, android, webview

I have two layouts (`start.xml` and `activity_main.xml`), My first activity `GubStartActivity.java` uses "start.xml" with a function that calls a `WebView`

```
public void disparaweb()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);       
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    myWebView.loadData("", "text/html", null);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl(Global.urlstr);
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
}
```

I use WebAppInterface.java as a JavaScript interface with my .net app.

Everything works, but i want to change URL in WebAppInterface and i can't get `WebView` with findViewById, it always return null, no matter what i use.

How can i get the myWebView element in `WebAppInterface.java`?

Comment: You can pass the reference of webview object as argument to you WebAppInterface.

Comment: How? I tried but didn't work.

Comment: i need to have a look at your WebAppInterface code.

Comment: https://github.com/vlntdds/Guberman.Pneu/blob/master/Guberman/src/com/ats/gubobj/WebAppInterface.java

Answer (score 1):

Ok , i think if you pass the webview as an argument to your WebAppInterface it should work, change this inside your WebAppInterface

```
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mBlueProbeAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
}
```

to

```
WebAppInterface(Context c, WebView webView) {
    mContext = c;
    this.myWebView=webView;
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mBlueProbeAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
}
```

and when you are setting this

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

set this to

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this, myWebView), "Android");
```

Comment: When i try to set myWebView.addJavascriptInterface it says that "The Constructor WebAppInterface(GubStartActivity, WebView) is indefined"

Comment: Did you change your constructor in WebAppInterface ?